# ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED Broadcast in Android O

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The dynamic broadcastreceiver below tested and worked on android studio emulator API 25 (Android N) but failed to received on API 26 (Android O).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i(getClass().getName(),intent.getAction());
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();
        intent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        intent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT);
        intent.addDataScheme("file");
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong on it?